# UIViewControllers - View1, View2, View3 displayed in succession

Tags: ios6

I have three UIViewControllers that I need to show in succession. The UIViewController1 is my main view controller and has a button. Clicking on the button displays UIViewController2 modally. After 30 seconds, UIViewController3 is automatially shown modally. Do I have to first dimiss UIViewcontroller2 and then display UIViewController3?. I have a Done button on UIViewcontroller3 and clicking on it should take me back to UIViewController1 (main view controller). Do I have first dismiss UIViewController2 from the chain and then do a alloc/init on UIViewController1 to show it?. I don't want to get any memory leaks in this process.

Please help.

Comment: Why are you using new viewcontrollers anyway? Why not just use UIViews?

Comment: I'm confused. When I mean UIViewControllers, I was referring to the UIViews and each of them is tied to their .xib files. I'm not using storyboards if I understood you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways that you can do this, one of which, you have alluded to. After testing this scenario in XCode.

The first involves dismissing all modal view controllers from the final view controller (the third). By doing this, you **cannot** use animation to dismiss the view controllers. If you try to animate them, the second will not be dismissed. (*Granted, you could dismiss the second one with animation, but it would display the animation from the second to the first, rather than from the third to the first*)

To do this, you'll need to pass your second view controller as a property to your third view controller so you can call the line:

```
[[self parentVC] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

*Note that parentVC is a property that should be set to point to the second view controller*

Then when dismissing:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[[self parentVC] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

This will take you back to the first view controller.

The second, which is not really better or worse, but is probably easier to code, is to dismiss the second view controller before going to the third; again, you probably will not want to animate the view controllers between the transition from the second to the third, but you **could** animate from the **third to the first**.

Comment: I'll try this tonight and let you know tomorrow. Thanks again

Comment: I'm getting what you're saying but is not working. Let me explain in detail in another thread. thanks.

Comment: The new question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868812/modal-view-controllers-showing-and-dismissing-issue

Comment: @Hema, my answer to your [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868812/modal-view-controllers-showing-and-dismissing-issue) is the detail on how to implement David's second suggestion. As regards his first suggestion, it requires more delicate treatment of objects, so I wouldn't recommend it.