# Push/pop to another view controller from a Modal View Controller (includes picture)

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, modalviewcontroller

I have two UIViewControllers called `VCA` & `VC B`. `VCB` has two child views that are presented as modal View Controllers. The two modal View Controllers are `M 1` And `M 2`. Is it possible to Go from `M2` to `VCA`? I need to pop off `M2` and go to `VCA` if possible. Pushing to `VCA` does not work because M2 does not have a navigation bar. And presenting `VCA` as a modal is not good because `VCA` needs to maintain its navigation bar.

So is it possible to jump from `M2` which is a Modal ViewController to `VCA`.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Hope this link will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907518/modal-view-controllers-how-to-display-and-dismiss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VCA has a link that says it's your root controller, which means it should be the base of your navigation stack.  So, instead of the branching diagram, you should have VCA -> VCB -> M1 -> M2 at run time.  I would look at having VCB listen for a notification that M2 is finished.  Then it can dismiss M1, which dismisses M2, and pop to the root view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [custom delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c?rq=1) for the M2 UIViewController, just dismiss the modal View with  respect to the delegate. and use the delegate method in the VC A controller to navigate to the VC B.

Comment: Do you mean "use the delegate method in VCB to navigate to VCA"? :)

Answer (score 0):

In Custom Function, we need to push navigationController object instead of particular object of viewController.**Use the following code in Swift 2**

```
    let objNextVC : SignUpOptionVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SignUpOptionVC") as! SignUpOptionVC
    let navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: objNextVC)
    navigation.navigationBarHidden = true
    self.navigationController?.presentViewController(navigation, animated: true, completion: nil)
```