# Hiding my backbutton in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am running to a new `viewcontroller` and am trying to remove the `back button` completely.  Here is what I am doing:

```
/* HIDE BACK BUTTON ON NAVIGATiON */
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
    //<!-- Make sure navigation bar shows
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
```

Now when I run this inside the `ViewController` `viewdidload()` of the current active controller it disabled the back button but the text `back` does not go away.  Before that I use a `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushToHomePage" sender:self];` to send it to the current `ViewController` that I am trying to remove the back button from.

Suggestions, thoughts?

Comment: Where are you making this call? Have you checked to make sure navigationItem exists when this is called? I'm calling this from -viewDidLoad with success. As well in other places after the view has been presented.

Comment: @DaveBatton I believe so.

Comment: @DaveBatton  I make this call within `- (void)viewDidLoad` of the newely pushed viewcontroller that I want to remove the back button from.

Comment: If you don't want a back button, you probably shouldn't be using UINavigationController.  Are you planning to disable the swipe-back gesture as well?  Try using modals instead.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907518/modal-view-controllers-how-to-display-and-dismiss

Answer (score 0):

For my experience, try to set to it to `nil` as well:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = nil;
```

Let me know ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the answer below by @MatteoGobbi is correct after validating in Xcode:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = nil;
```