# Method in NSTimer Selector is invalid

Tags: xcode, swift

```
self.presentViewController(playerViewController, animated: true){
        self.playerViewController.player?.play()
        self.playerTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(4, target: self, selector:Selector("stopAfter4seconds:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

    func stopAfter4seconds(timer: NSTimer){
    self.playerViewController.player?.pause()
    self.playerViewController.player = nil
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    self.presentViewController(GameViewController1(), animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

So.. I've tried just about everything to get this NSTimer to work and nothing seems to go correctly.
I've tried:

1. Adding & Removing colon in between

   ```
   ("stopAfter4seconds:")
   ```
2. Adding & Removing the (timer:NSTimer) in the parameter of the

   ```
   stopAfter4seconds()
   ```
3. Adding & Removing the second Selector in

   ```
   selector:Selector("stopAfter4seconds:")
   ```

Errors I'm getting:

1. stopAfter4seconds]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7bb1ae90
2. Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'
3. Thread 1 : signal SIGABRT

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong so please if anyone has any idea let me know.

Comment: I couldn't get what you want to do.

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27435406/2125010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the method is defined like so:

```
func stopAfter4seconds(timer: NSTimer) { ... }
```

Then you'd create the timer like so:

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(4, target: self, selector: Selector("stopAfter4seconds:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

Or you can omit `Selector()` and just do:

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(4, target: self, selector: "stopAfter4seconds:", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

It would appear, though, that you've implemented this `stopAfter4seconds` function inside the method that called `presentViewController`. This `stopAfter4seconds`, itself, must be a method, not defined inside another method.

Answer (score 1):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        print("run viewDidAppear")
        myFunction1()
    }


    func myFunction1() {
        print("call timer")
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("myFunction2"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

    func myFunction2(){
        print("do stuff")
    }
}
```

Comment: My NStimer is in the method override func viewDidAppear(animated:Bool)

Comment: should I move all the code to a new method, then call that method into the viewDidAppear?

Comment: I guess so, try to move your function into class.

Comment: moved my function into the entire class view at the top, it did not seem to help

Comment: Can you explain briefly when do you want to run `NSTimer?` After closing the `presentViewController` ?

Comment: Yes, My goal is to Run the NSTimer after 4 seconds (i.e. how long the video is), then present another view.

Comment: Got it!!! It was a combination moving the function to the entire class view and adding the colon back to the selector  :) thanks again